# Dropdown it shown below the ScrollBar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

See the following code:

```
    <div ng-controller="DropdownCtrl">
    <div style="height: 100px; overflow-y: auto;">


        <!-- Single button -->
        <div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" ng-disabled="disabled">
                Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/DwQIi6ipDgN9LIOe5TqR?p=preview

I know that the problem is the height of the div, but I need to leave the height as is.
See the screenshot from my project:
[image]

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: Is [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/aWf6bH8WNNe17B6aUgUM?p=preview) what you need? Just modified the overflow to make it visible without scrollbar.

Comment: remove the overflow-y: auto;

Comment: But I need the scrollbar!

Answer (score 0):

I use position:fixed but it is not ok, because you use overflow:

[image]

[image]

if don't use position:fixed, Remove overflow..